# I use POST methon in Django, but my request.method == 'POST' said that it's GET method

Tags: python, django, python-requests, http-post

I don't know why the create function worked before, but now is not working. I see only "It's not POST, it's GET". I have tried to delete something, for example:
from `def index(request)`:

```
email = str(request.GET.get('autorization_email'))
```

and from `def create(request)`

```
type_values = Type.objects.all()
model_values = Model.objects.all()
equipment_values = Equipment.objects.all()
```

It didn't help

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.autorization, name='autorization'),
    path('home/', views.index, name='home'),
    path('return_equpment/', views.return_equpment, name='return_equpment'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

create.html

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'create' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button><br>
    <span>{{ error }}</span><br>
  </form>
{% endblock%}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Booking, Type, Model, Equipment
from .forms import BookingForm


error = ''
email = ''


def index(request):
    global email
    global error

    email = str(request.GET.get('autorization_email'))

    context = {
        'title': 'Main page',
        'error': error,
        'index_email': email
    }

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)

def create(request):
    type_values = Type.objects.all()
    model_values = Model.objects.all()
    equipment_values = Equipment.objects.all()
    form2 = BookingForm()
    global error
    global email

    context = {
        'form': form2,
        'error': error,
        'type_values': type_values,
        'model_values': model_values,
        'equipment_values': equipment_values,
        'create_email': email
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = BookingForm(request.POST)
        form2.email = email
        form2.type = request.POST.get('type')
        form2.model = request.POST.get('model')
        form2.number = request.POST.get('number')
        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
            return redirect('autorization')
        else:
            error = 'Form incorrect'
    else:
        error = 'It's not POST, it's '+request.method
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', context)
```

Comment: Please *don't* use global variables (this is a *very severe* antipattern): it might be possible that the `error` is set at some time, and thus keeps containing that message, while it is already processed correctly.

Comment: Other than the usage of the global variables you have your context declared before you set the `error` etc. variables in your function... i.e. you're just saving that  value for the **next** request (and all requests after that, since you never reset that variable). Strings are **not mutable** hence when you update the value of your variable all other reference to your value won't also be updated...

Comment: Please don't worry about global variables. I know that it's not good. But right now I'm just trying to make a working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Booking, Type, Model, Equipment
from .forms import BookingForm


error = ''
email = ''


def index(request):
    global email
    global error

    email = str(request.GET.get('autorization_email'))

    context = {
        'title': 'Main page',
        'error': error,
        'index_email': email
    }

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)

def create(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = BookingForm(request.POST)
        form2.email = email
        form2.type = request.POST.get('type')
        form2.model = request.POST.get('model')
        form2.number = request.POST.get('number')
        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
            return redirect('autorization')
        else:
            error = 'Form incorrect'
    else:
         type_values = Type.objects.all()
         model_values = Model.objects.all()
         equipment_values = Equipment.objects.all()
         form2 = BookingForm()
         global error
         global email

         context = {
            'form': form2,
             'error': error,
             'type_values': type_values,
             'model_values': model_values,
             'equipment_values': equipment_values,
             'create_email': email
          }
        error = 'It's not POST, it's '+request.method
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure but I think

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Should be in the first of function

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

Because Django by default make a function as get request and you make some operations before you specific the request type

Comment: If I put "if request.method == 'POST':" on the first position, my program still considers it a GET method using in function